# IUSR permissions regarding running an external exe with php's exec()

Tags: windows, batch-file, iis, cmd, permissions

Hello Stack Overflowers,

I've been working on a project for my employer regarding automating document printing to a workable PDF file with the application PrintShop Mail Suite 7.

The process I have imagined goes as follows:

You create an order with a PHP application, which retrieves data from and in turn is persisted in an MSSQL database.

The same application generates a temporary XML file from the persisted SQL entry, which is readable by the application PrintShop Mail, in conjunction with a template file.

The next step of my process would be a batch file, ran from this application, which generates a PDF in an assigned folder in the PHP application's folder.

However, I can't get the batch script to run with PHP's [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command.
The batch file is built up as follows:

```
cd E:\Printshop\Template

copy /y Reisbureau.psmd order_67.psmd

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\PrintShop Mail Suite 7\PrintShop Mail\PSMail.exe" order_67.psmd -db "exportFile.xml" -pt "PDFCreator"
```

If I run this file "as is" (navigate to the batch file in explorer, run it), it will process the batch as planned.
If PHP runs it, it seems to do the top 2 lines, and stop at the 3rd line, supposedly due to a permission issue.

After a check which user is running the batch, it turned out to be `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`

However, after giving the mentioned user `Full Control` to the batch file and the application PSMail.exe, it still refuses to process the batch file.

[Permissions seem to be in place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCtcu.png)

I hope I have provided enough information for the IIS- and script-savvy alike to look into this, and hopefully provide some more insight on this matter.

With kind regards,

Rik Bastiaens

Comment: I think the problem is that `start` spawns a new process so your php code won't know when it completes. Either remove `start ""` or use its `/wait` parameter: `start "" /wait "c:\program files ........`

Comment: Hello wOxxOm, 
Thank you for your reply, at this moment I´m back at the office.
I will try your suggestion and keep you posted on the progress.